How to prevent duplicate inserts without Serializable transaction?
I have an API, where an insert to tableA happens after validating the result of a select query on some other tables. So tableA can have no unique keys other than the auto-generated ID.
Therefore concurrent requests to this API create duplicate entries in tableA instead of one.
This API's latency is very high, I have a lot of bulk inserts happening with two other tables (tableB and tableC), so I cannot make this transaction serializable since that would lock all three tables.
One solution I could think of is having another table called lock where I have a unique composite key which I insert after validating the select query. Since repeatable read takes a lock on this key, this avoids duplication in the original API and also does not block the tables A B and C for other requests.
But the problem is, since the transaction is write-heavy, while the concurrent requests with the same unique key may wait on the lock table they will proceed with the inserts anyway and only fail while committing the transaction.
Is there any other efficient solution to this problem?

Database locks and unique constraints are the two ways of avoiding concurrency issues. In a write-heavy environment, both could cause performance bottlenecks. It is a business decision what is more important: performance or business transaction consistency.

My 2c, maybe you need to do it in an optimistic locking approach.

@TszLam how would I do it with an insert though?

"tableA can have no unique keys other than the auto-generated ID." How does that follow from the first sentence?
